# NodeJS Promise returns [Object Undefined]

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem. I am doing a database call to collect an Id from an order I have in my DB, then I want to return the Id of that order using promise, because a database call is async. I made the following promise:

```
function getNextOrderId() {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        orderIdSelected = 0;

        var sql = `
           SELECT * 
            FROM Orders 
            WHERE userId=5
        `;

        conn.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var length1 = Object.keys(rows).length;

            LogToConsole("length1="+length1);   
            i1 = 0
            while (i1 < length1 && orderIdSelected == 0) {
                
                var OrderId = rows[i1].Id;

                LogToConsole("OrderId="+OrderId);

                if (OrderId == 1134881) {
                    orderIdSelected = OrderId;
                    LogToConsole("orderIdSelected end="+orderIdSelected);
                    resolve(toString(orderIdSelected));
                }
                
                i1++;
                
            }
                
        });
        
    });

}
```

Then I call the promise like this below:

```
getNextOrderId().then(function(nextOrderId) {

    LogToConsole(nextOrderId);
            
}).catch((err) => setImmediate(() => { throw err; }));
```

But nextOrderId is `[Object Undefined]`, where it has a value in the promise function right before it returns it. The print: `LogToConsole("orderIdSelected end="+orderIdSelected);` gives: `orderIdSelected end=1134881`.... What is going wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? This code feels weird and complicated. Like, you fetch all Orders of this user from the DB to node just to sift through tha list and determine wether it contains a given Id, and then you resolve that given Id. Why don't you let the DB do the sifting, like as it if it is built for exactly that kind of task. And what has this with the name of the method to do `getNextOrderId`? Or the loop, i'm quite sure this will do: `const selected = rows.find(order => order.Id === 1134881);`. Or the memory leak when nothing is found, ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`toString(1134881)` gives `"[object Undefined]"`

Just `resolve(orderIdSelected);` or `resolve(orderIdSelected.toString());`

More details on `toString` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp)